# Methods intended for overriding but not part of the public API

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a class that implements a strategy. As part of a wider strategy API it has a public interface. In this particular class the `main_method` applies various conditions and has a `helper_...` method for each condition. Thus, by subclassing and overriding these helper methods you can change the behaviour of the strategy. This is intended. However, these helper methods are not part of the API that is being implemented/exposed to the client.

It seems to me that these methods should be considered private, as they are not part of the interface that is being implemented, but on the other hand they are intended to be overridden by subclasses. In Java they would be "protected".

What's the pythonic way to deal with this situation? My code is schematically similar to the following:

```
class BasicFoo(Object):

    def __init__(self):
         pass

    def main_method(self, input) :
        if condition_1 :
            self._helper1(input)
        elif condition_2 :
            self._helper2(input)
        else :
            self._helper3(input)

    def _helper1(self, input)
        # do something

    def _helper2(self, input):
        # do something else

    def _helper3(self, input):
        # do something else again

class ModifiedFoo(BasicFoo):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ModifiedFoo, self).__init__()

    def _helper1(self, input):
        # a different behaviour
```

Comment: What is the problem with what you have now? Who is implementing these subclasses? Do they have a problem with overriding private-by-convention methods?

Comment: I think a better place for this would be here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DeanFenster Or you could [read what's on-topic for Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and learn that hypothetical code will be closed right away there.

Comment: The "problem", is that I am not sure what is best/most accepted/most pythonic/most readable for implementing this type of pattern in python. Or if you should do iti at all, as I could wrap the helper methods into a new object with its own abstract base class and compose it in, for example, which avoids this problem, though adds more lines.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the methods public and clarify their intended use in the documentation. Take the example from the [`ast.NodeVisitor`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) class from the standard library:

> This class is meant to be subclassed, with the subclass adding visitor
>   methods.
>
> `visit(node)`
>
> Visit a node. The default implementation calls the method called `self.visit_classname` where `classname` is the name of the node class, or
>   `generic_visit()` if that method doesn’t exist.

Given that in Python you don't have the access modifiers you can only rely on documentation and conventions to clarify the roles of such methods.
In this case your methods *are* part of the public API (a private attribute/method could be renamed at leisure between releases, but this isn't the case here).